# "Can't normalize array. Sum is NaN." while classifying instance weka

Tags: c#, java, weka

I am developing a prototype for my research, I have the trained model and I want to test with my test set.

I am using c# to develop the program. This is the code

```
            Classifier cls = null;
            cls = (Classifier)weka.core.SerializationHelper.read("Multinomial.model");


            //sample arff file

            //@relation emotion_class
            //@attribute Text string
            //@attribute class_list {Happy,Fear,Anger,Sad,Neutral}
            //@data
            //" ang saya saya #PlanPhilippines team interviewing #Bopha survivors Mindanao. ",

            StringBuilder buffer = new StringBuilder(sample);
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new java.io.StringReader(buffer.ToString()));
            weka.core.converters.ArffLoader.ArffReader arff = new weka.core.converters.ArffLoader.ArffReader(reader);
            Instances dataRaw = arff.getData();

            //converts tweets to string to word vector
            StringToWordVector filter = new StringToWordVector();
            filter.setInputFormat(dataRaw);
            Instances dataFiltered = Filter.useFilter(dataRaw, filter);
            dataFiltered.setClassIndex(dataFiltered.numAttributes() - 1);


            for (int i = 0; i < dataFiltered.numInstances();i++ )
            {

                Instance inst = dataFiltered.instance(i);

                double classified = cls.classifyInstance(inst);
               MessageBox.Show(dataFiltered.classAttribute().value((int)classified));
            }
```

I got an error: Can't normalize array. Sum is NaN. in `double classified = cls.classifyInstance(inst);`

But when I remove the string to word vector filter.. no error but it outputs wrong result it always give 1 or Happy.

Thanks!

Comment: You should rephrase this to actually ask a question. Are you unsure what `NaN` means? It is a special value of `double` that often arises if you do a meaningless mathematical operation, such as `0.0 / 0.0` or `Math.Sqrt(-4)`.

Comment: But I doesn't divide or process a mathematical operation. cls.classifyInstance(inst) is a built in method in weka.

Comment: How are you creating the `cls` variable? It's not in your code.

Comment: Either that method is trying to do some floating point arithmetic and bubbling up an exception because you call it with some values which cause it to attempt an operation like `0.0/0.0` OR you could just be wrong about the source of your error. Keep in mind the cast on the following line will throw on special values like NaN or infinity.

Comment: @MagnusGrindalBakken: Sorry, I edited my code now.